# Unable to .Activate Word application

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, paste, office-automation

I'm writing a macro to paste a bunch of tables and charts into a Word doc to be uploaded to our underwriters' system. I've tried to do a small sample and keep getting an error that the Word Application can't be activated.

```
Sub PasteToWord()

Dim wordapp As Word.Appliation

Dim worddoc As Word.Document

Dim xlrng As Range

Set wordapp = New Word.Application

wordapp.Activate

wordapp.Visible = True

Set worddoc = wordapp.Documents.Add

Set xlrng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10")

xlrng.copy

worddoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable False, True, False

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim wordapp As Word.Appliation` typo on application.

Comment: Moving `wordapp.Activate` after `wordapp.Visible = True` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to display the application before activating anything:

```
Sub PasteToWord()
  Dim wordapp As Word.Appliation
  Dim worddoc As Word.Document
  Dim xlrng As Range
  Set wordapp = New Word.Application
  
  wordapp.Visible = True
  wordapp.Activate
  
  Set worddoc = wordapp.Documents.Add
  Set xlrng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10")
  xlrng.copy
  worddoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable False, True, False
End Sub
```